# How to summarize in joined tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables:

- "Item_Table"
- "Order_Table"
- "Order_Scores"

"Item_Table" with "code1" can connect with "code" to "Order_Scores"

"Order_Table" with "number" can connect with "number" to "Order_Scores"

I need to summarize "count" column in "Order_Scores" who grouped by "code" clolumn and "type" column is "req".

I wrote this query:

```
select Item_Table.*,
(select SUM(cast (Order_Scores.count AS INT)) from Order_Table left outer join Order_Scores on Order_Table.number=Order_Scores.number where Order_Table.type='req' group by Order_Scores.code ) AS ReqOrderTotall
from Item_Table left outer join Order_Scores on Item_Table.code1= Order_Scores.code
```

...but I received an error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>      Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
select Item_Table.*,
       (select SUM(cast (Order_Scores.count AS INT))
        from Order_Table left outer join
             Order_Scores
             on Order_Table.number=Order_Scores.number
             where Order_Table.type = 'req'
        group by Order_Scores.code
       ) AS ReqOrderTotall
from Item_Table left outer join
     Order_Scores
     on Item_Table.code1 = Order_Scores.code ;
```

There are several issues with this query, but your problem is caused by the `group by` in the subquery.  As the error message says, this returns more than one row.  In addition, you don't need the `Order_Scores` table in the outer query.  The result is something like this, although I'm not sure if the correlation is correct:

```
select it.*,
       (select SUM(cast(Order_Scores.count AS INT))
        from Order_Table ot join
             Order_Scores os
             on ot.number = os.number
        where ot.type = 'req' and ot.item_id = it.item_id
----------------------------------^
       ) AS ReqOrderTotall
from Item_Table it;
```

Comment: i have received this error :</br>
Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The column prefix 'Item_Table' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Never use a correlated subquery. They are performance killers. Use a derived table instead.

```
select Item_Table.*,Totals.ReqOrderTotal
 from Item_Table 
left outer join  Order_Scores
     on Item_Table.code1 = Order_Scores.code 
left outer join
 (select  Order_Scores.code, SUM(cast (Order_Scores.count AS INT))as ReqOrderTotal
        from Order_Table left outer join
             Order_Scores
             on Order_Table.number=Order_Scores.number
             where Order_Table.type = 'req'
        group by Order_Scores.code
       ) Totals
      on Totals.code= Order_Scores.code
```

Of course it is a SQL antipattern to use select * so please replace that with the actual field names you need.